# How to configure Flyway with Yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml, flyway

I have a spring boot project, and I need to configure Flyway in my `application.yml` file.

Does anyone know how to do this with Yaml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look into this [Flyway doc](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot)

### Application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: ${DRIVER}
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    validate-on-migrate: true
```

#### Dependency

`implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'`

Comment: Actually it seems it's `user` and not `username`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data-migration.spring.flyway.user or https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/gradle/#java-migrations-and-callbacks

Comment: Flyway is not a Spring component, so shouldn't the Flyway properties be under their own tree? Or in your app-specific tree? Or maybe I'm the outdated one... per https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway